# How to stop the icon jumping effect in kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

[the desktop-jump-effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGoam.jpg)

Do i need to use **kcmshell5** for it? I am using plasma 5.5.5. and kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This animation is really problematic. In 2021 it' s still activated by default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Application Launch Feedback**

[image]

KDE Help Center - Launch Feedback:

> Sometimes it is reassuring to know that your computer didn't just
>   ignore your command, and something is happening behind the scenes. In
>   this module you can configure visible feedback to help you know if you
>   really hit that icon or not.
>
> The traditional way to indicate that your computer is busy is to
>   modify the cursor, and you can turn this on by choosing a Busy Cursor.
>   With this option enabled, your cursor will have an icon attached to it
>   for a short time, when a new application is being launched. You can
>   configure how long this icon is displayed beside your cursor with the
>   Startup indication timeout: spinbox. The default is 5 seconds.
>
> There are several variations of busy cursor available, including a
>   Blinking Cursor, a Bouncing Cursor or a Passive Busy Cursor icon with
>   no animation...

KDE System Settings > Personalization - Applications > Launch Feedback

[image]

As a single KDE control module

```
kcmshell5 kcmlaunch
```

Comment: That was easy, stupid me!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When I type the command "# kcmshell5 launchfeedback" to the terminal to change my mouse animation, a white window was opened. And the "launch feedback" that I found by searching for the word "launch" in the start menu is the dark window. It says "system settings module" in the window titles. Someone has the phrase <2>. And the window that says <2> is the correct one. Somehow Static was chosen by itself. And I didn't change that. Somehow it happened by itself. Also, I don't know why there were 2 of these modules.